# How can you find the complex roots of i?

Tags: complex-numbers

A variation of the [Root of Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roots_of_unity) problem.

I want to find all possible answers to this:

$$z^n = i$$

Where $$i^2 = -1$$

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/what-is-the-square-root-of-i, which asks for a special case, but whose answers give you everything you need and more.

Comment: By the way, your title doesn't quite match your question. Any purely imaginary root of unity must be an n-th root where n is a multiple of 4 (for example, (-i)^4 = 1).

Comment: @weltschmerz I don't know what to call it then?

Comment: "All n-th roots of i" would do.

Comment: Or, if you want to emphasize that they're not real, you could refer to "complex roots of i".

Comment: You should not refer to "complex roots of i" in the title, it is obvious they must be complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the polar form of $z$ is $$z=r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta),$$ there are $n$ distinct solutions to the equation $w^n = z$: $$w=\sqrt[n]{r}(\cos\frac{\theta +2\pi k}{n}+ i \sin\frac{\theta +2\pi k}{n}),$$ where $k=0,1,...,n-1$. In your case, $z=i$, whose polar form is given by $r=1$, $\theta = \pi /2$.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, the answers would be of the form

$$\sqrt[n]{i}\omega_n^j$$

where $\omega_n=\exp\left(\frac{2i\pi}{n}\right)$ is a root of unity, and $j=0\dots n-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Also, observe that if $z^n=i$ then $z^{4n}=1$. Thus, the complex numbers you're looking for are particular $4n$-th roots of $1$.

If you know that the $m$-th roots of 1 (any $m$) can be written as powers of a single well-chosen one (a primitive root), it shouldn't be too hardto find exactly which $4n$-th roots have the desired property.