# Show that for any complex number W, there exists a non-zero complex number Z such that Z + 1/Z = W

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Can anyone help me with this proof? I am not sure how to exactly go about this using just variables such as a + bi ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Perhaps let W=a+bi, and Z=c+di. Then it is just a matter of finding c and d. So, determine the real and imaginary part of 1/Z, and add it to Z to get a complex number in terms of c and d. Now you should have an expression from which you can solve for x and d in terms of a and b...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** $\:\mathbb C$ algebraically closed $\rm\Rightarrow\: f(z) = z^2 - w\: z + 1\:$ has a root  $\rm\:r\in\mathbb C.\:$ $\rm\:r\ne 0\:$ since $\rm\:f(0) = 1.$

To determine the root simply apply the quadratic formula, and see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44406/242) on calculating square roots of complex numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help Bill. I think I got it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You really don't need anything as sophisticated as knowing that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed in order to know that you can solve quadratic equations within $\mathbb{C}$, do you?

Comment: @Michael See the link.

Comment: @MichaelHardy: But then you can solve the same problem for many more cases.

Answer (score 0):

The angle from the positive real axis to the ray from $0$ through $a+bi$ is $\theta=\arctan(b/a)$ if $a\ge0$ and $\theta=\pi+\arctan(b/a)$ if $a<0$.  For the square root, you want just half that angle.

The absolute value $|a+bi|$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.  For the square root of $a+bi$, you want the square root of that, so that's $\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}$.

So you get
$$
\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}\left(\cos\frac\theta2 + i\sin\frac\theta2\right).
$$