# The square root of $1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I know this is wrong but I don't know why.
In the set of complex numbers:
$\sqrt1 = \sqrt{i^2\cdot i^2} = i\cdot i = -1$
What is wrong with this?

Comment: What are you using $\sqrt{}$ to mean?

Comment: See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number?rq=1), please. The square root function is not well-defined on the complex numbers.

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ is no longer an identity for complex numbers.

Answer (score 2):

One must take care when defining $\sqrt{}$ for complex numbers; it's not generally true that the square root of a product is the product of the square roots.

Although this is true for non-negative real numbers, it doesn't extend in full generality.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I've checked $-1$ squared was equal to one. That would be the usual way of checking if the root is calculated correctly.

Comment: $\sqrt x$ is normally defined to be the *non-negative* number $y$ such that $y^2 = x$.

Comment: Well, that might be one of the reasons why this question is really a bit imprecise. "Wrong" as OP stated it would require more context.