# Solve $(x+iy)^2=8+6i$, for $x$ and $y$

Tags: complex-numbers

Given $(x+iy)^2 = 8+6i$, find the values of $x$ and $y$. Hence find $\sqrt{8+6i}$.

My question is when we solve we get $x = 3$ and $x = -3$, which give and $y = 1$ and $y = -1$ then Why $-3-i$ is not the solution of $\sqrt{8+6i}$ ?

Comment: What is $(-3-i)^2$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the square root of a complex number?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number)

Answer (score 3):

To check the solution, we have to square $z$ and ideally get the RHS($8+6i)$
$(-3-i)(-3-i)=9+3i+3i+i^2=6i+9-1=8+6i$ as needed
So, $-3-i$ is in fact a solution and is *equal to* $\sqrt{8+6i}$

Comment: Thanks for the clarification John, I had the confusion because both the answer in the back of the book and wolfram alpha did't show (-3-6i)

Comment: @user115368 It should be noted that the square root function is not well defined for complex numbers. Wolfram Alpha and perhaps your book were giving you the principal root-which has the positive real component. You may find more information asked by another person here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number