# How to find the solution of a quadratic equation with complex coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I know how to find the solution for a quadratic equation with real coefficients. But if the coefficient changes to complex numbers then what is the change in the solution? Want an example of such equation with solution.

Comment: Same as usual formula. Just need to be careful with the branches of square root.

Comment: But how to find the two square roots of a complex number ??

Comment: "How to find the two square roots of a complex number" -- see the link in my answer below.

Comment: Write the complex number in exponential form (for example, $i = e^{i {\pi \over 2}}$, hence $\sqrt{i} = \pm e^{i {\pi \over 4}} = \pm {1+i \over \sqrt{2}}$).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's no different.  [The quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula_and_its_derivation) works regardless of whether the coefficients are real or complex.

Consider the example
$$(3+i)x^2 + (2-i)x + (5+2i) = 0$$

The quadratic formula gives

$$x = \frac{-(2-i) \pm \sqrt{ (2-i)^2-4(3+i)(5+2i) } }{2(3+i)}$$

Simplifying this is kind of a pain, of course.  Under the radical you have to multiply everything out and combine terms.  Eventually you get the radical into the form $\sqrt{M+Ni}$ where $M$ and $N$ are some constants -- in this example, they will be integers.  Then the question is, how do you simplify the square root of a complex number?  (For that, see [How do I get the square root of a complex number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number)).

Answer (score -4):

Let's see if this works.  Kind of unclear how to use these tools, so I just was going to snapshot a quick writeup.

[image]

Comment: You can learn how to use the formatting [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).