# How does the quadratic formula work for complex variables?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose for $z, a, b, c \in \mathbb{C}$ that we have $az^2+bz+c=0,$ how do you define solutions in the complex plane? Can you even use the quadratic formula at all for the non-real case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the solution of a quadratic equation with complex coefficients?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/859334/how-to-find-the-solution-of-a-quadratic-equation-with-complex-coefficients)

Comment: Why not? Many quadratic Equations have complex roots

Comment: It doesn't quite because that problem seems to assume a real variable, whereas I have a complex variable with any coefficient. Basically I want to know when a solution is valid, I don't want to be bogged down having to analyze 50 different branch technicalities.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928516/quadratic-formula-for-complex-variable-with-real-coefficients/928553#928553

Comment: Both of those are half-right. One of them says real variable complex coefficients, the other says complex variable real coefficients. I'm looking for complex variable with complex coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it works the same way it does in the "real case".   If the discriminant, $b^2-4ac\ne0$, then there are two complex roots.  If the discriminant is zero, then there is one complex root.

At any rate, the formula provides the two solutions guaranteed by the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: If one *starts* with a quadratic having 2 real roots (and positive discriminant), then multiplies its coefficients all by $i,$ the discriminant gets its sign changed. But still the roots are real.

Comment: So the fact that the square root function is a completely different function in the complex plane than in the real plane is somehow irrelevant? What's the point of complex analysis then?

Comment: Sorry again.  My statement about the discriminant was incorrect.  Of course we can't compare $b^2-4ac$ and $0$ in general.