# Why is the following equivalent transformation of the imaginary number legitimate?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Why is this substitution acceptable?

$\sqrt{i}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Square it and see.

Comment: Oh man, you guys are so incredibly fast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $i = e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and $\sqrt{i} = i^{\frac{1}{2}} = e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}} = \cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + i \cdot \sin(\frac{\pi}{4}) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}i$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a+ib=re^{i\theta}$$
where $r^2=|a^2+b^2|$ & $ \theta=\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{b}{a}\right)$

Then 
$$i=e^{i\pi/2}$$

$$i^{1/2}=e^{i\pi/4}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+i\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that
$$\sqrt{i} = a+bi$$
Then, as per Yves Daoust's suggestion,
$$\sqrt{i}^2=i=0+i=(a+bi)^2=a^2+2abi+b^2i^2=(a^2-b^2)+(2ab)i$$
summarizing we have
$$0+i=(a^2-b^2)+(2ab)i$$
All that is now required is to solve the system
$$0=a^2+b^2$$
$$1=2ab$$