# What is the difference between radical and exponent?

Tags: complex-numbers, terminology, exponentiation

Is radical a type of exponent? What do we call the power when it is a complex number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A radical $x^\frac{1}{n}$ (the $n$th root of $x$) is a subset of exponents $x^y$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $y\in\mathbb{R}$.

You can still use the terms "exponent" and "power" when $x\in\mathbb{C}$, but radicals are [more ill-defined](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number).

Comment: @ankit Did this answer your question?

Comment: yes @Lovsovs, it does answer.

Answer (score 0):

They are different things even if related. The  sign in front of  the radical symbol of  power or exponent can be either positive or negative in example given:

$$  e ^ {\pm  \sqrt{ x^2- a x + b \sin \omega t} } $$

The radical is a special symbol expressing exponents with different symbolization used for powers and roots only.