# Need clarification on how to proceed with this.

Tags: complex-numbers

Can you help me in solving this equation? Thanks in advance :)

$(x + iy)^2 = 5 + 4i$

Comment: Write $x+i y = r e^{i \theta}$.

Comment: You are asked to get the square roots of $5+4i.$ See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number

Comment: In the future: titles should be descriptive. You LaTeX markup. Give us info about what methods or attempts you know or have tried. You'll get more help that way.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy = 5 + 4i$

Equating real and imaginary parts

$x^2-y^2 = 5$

$xy = 2$

That should be enough, right ?

Comment: Please use LaTeX markup in the future.

Comment: Note the OP's *earlier* question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2049848/how-to-solve-this-equation-x2-y2-5-xy-2-find-x-and-y

Answer (score 1):

$$ x^2+2xyi-y^2=5+4i$$
$$x^2-y^2=5\tag1$$
$$2xy=4 \tag2$$
then solve the two equations

Answer (score 1):

The square root is not a well defined function on complex numbers. If you want to find out the possible values, the easiest way is probably to go with "De Moivre's formula", that is, converting your number into the form

$$r(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))$$ and then you will get,

$$(r(\cos(\theta)+ i \sin(\theta)))^{1/2} = ±[\sqrt{r}(\cos(\theta/2) + i \sin(\theta/2))]$$.