# Find the value of $√(4+6\sqrt{5}i) + √(4-6\sqrt{5}i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the value of $\sqrt{(4+6\sqrt{5}i)} + \sqrt{(4-6\sqrt{5}i)}$

$\sqrt{(4+6\sqrt{5}i)} = ± (3+\sqrt{5}i)$

$\sqrt{(4-6\sqrt{5}i)} = ± (3-\sqrt{5}i)$

There are two solutions to each which implies on adding them together, we will get four combinations and four different answers.

These answers are $6,-6,-2\sqrt{5}i,2\sqrt{5}i$.

But the only answer given in my book is $6$; they have only taken the + and + combination. Why we don't take the remaining three combinations? Why aren't all four the answers?

Comment: The two complex numbers you are adding are conjugates of each other, hence the sum must be real.

Comment: Okay, but that still doesn't reject -6 as the answer.

Comment: Typically the $n $th root of a non-real complex number is considered to be that with the largest positive real part.

Comment: Cotton: in general for such problems the concept of principle square root of a complex number is intended. For more details, check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number

Comment: Evaluate the square and the cube.

Answer (score 0):

I think the book means the following.
$$\left(\sqrt{4+6\sqrt5i}+\sqrt{4-6\sqrt5i}\right)^2=8+2\cdot14=36$$
and the book gets $\sqrt{4+6\sqrt5i}+\sqrt{4-6\sqrt5i}=6$.

This reasoning is wrong, of course.

Comment: No it's just taxonomy, basically, see the comments.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi I think the answer of Cotton is true. I tried to show a wrong solution from the book.