# Strategy to take absolute value of complicated complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to take the absolute value of the following expression:

$$c_1e^{ic_2}+ic_3e^{-ic_6}\sqrt{c_4+c_5i}$$

One strategy might be to separate it into the form $a+ib$, but how to handle the term inside the square root?

(all the constants $c_n$ are real)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the square root of a complex number is:

$$\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}=\Re\left(\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\right)+\Im\left(\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\right)\cdot i\tag1$$

Where:

- $$\Re\left(\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\text{c}_4^2+\text{c}_5^2}+\text{c}_4}{2}}\tag2$$
- $$\Im\left(\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\right)=\pm\space\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\text{c}_4^2+\text{c}_5^2}-\text{c}_4}{2}}\tag3$$

So, we get:

- $$\Re\left(\text{c}_1\cdot\exp\left(\text{c}_2\cdot i\right)+\text{c}_3\cdot\exp\left(-\text{c}_6\cdot i\right)\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\cdot i\right)=$$
  $$\Re\left(\text{c}_1\cdot\exp\left(\text{c}_2\cdot i\right)\right)+\Re\left(\text{c}_3\cdot\exp\left(-\text{c}_6\cdot i\right)\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\cdot i\right)=$$
  $$\text{c}_1\cdot\cos\left(\text{c}_2\right)+\text{c}_3\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\text{c}_4^2+\text{c}_5^2}+\text{c}_4}{2}}\cdot\sin\left(\text{c}_6\right)\mp\space\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\text{c}_4^2+\text{c}_5^2}-\text{c}_4}{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\text{c}_6\right)\right)\tag4$$
- $$\Im\left(\text{c}_1\cdot\exp\left(\text{c}_2\cdot i\right)+\text{c}_3\cdot\exp\left(-\text{c}_6\cdot i\right)\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\cdot i\right)=$$
  $$\Im\left(\text{c}_1\cdot\exp\left(\text{c}_2\cdot i\right)\right)+\Im\left(\text{c}_3\cdot\exp\left(-\text{c}_6\cdot i\right)\cdot\sqrt{\text{c}_4+\text{c}_5\cdot i}\cdot i\right)=$$
  $$\text{c}_1\cdot\sin\left(\text{c}_2\right)+\text{c}_3\cdot\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\text{c}_4^2+\text{c}_5^2}+\text{c}_4}{2}}\cdot\cos\left(\text{c}_6\right)\pm\space\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\text{c}_4^2+\text{c}_5^2}-\text{c}_4}{2}}\cdot\sin\left(\text{c}_6\right)\right)\tag5$$

Comment: (2) and (3) are new for me; how does that come about?

Comment: @axsvl77 Have a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number

Comment: Wow Thanks. Is this the best strategy to get the absolute value to the expression?

Comment: @axsvl77 I think that you don't have  a choice. So yes