# Problem with square roots of complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to tackle a question related with complex number and its square roots. My thoughts so far are below it.

```
(a)Given that (x+iy)^2=-5+12i,x and y belongs to real numbers, show that:

  (i)x^2-y^2=-5
  (ii)xy=6
```

It is easy for me to solve this first question, and what I only need to do do is extending the left side of the equation and get the results.
But what really makes me confused is the rest of the question:

```
(b)Hence find the two square roots of -5+12i
```

How can I find a root of a complex number? Using the viete’s formula?
What I only know is to find z from z^n=rcosθ.

Then it asks:

```
(C)for any complex number z, show that (z*)^2=(z^2)^*

(D)hence write down the two square roots of -5-12i
```

I thought C is easy to prove.Maybe I can suppose z=a+bi and z^*=a-bi and plug them into the equation provided.But how can it helps to find the roots??

How can I solve this problem ?? Help

Comment: (b) means "solve the equations in (a) for $x$ and $y$"

Comment: Ohhh! You mean find x and y?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$. For $(b)$, you need to solve $x^2-y^2=-5$ and $xy=6$. This is not too difficult to solve using Theo Bendit's answer but a nice trick is to remark that

$$x^2+y^2=|z|^2=|z^2|=|-5+12i|=13$$

Call this equation (iii). (i) and (iii) are linear in $x^2$ and $y^2$, so the system they form is easy to solve. We obtain $x^2=4$ and $y^2=9$, so $x=\pm2$ and $y=\pm3$.

This gives for possibilities for $(x,y)$ but only 2 are solutions of the problem since $xy=6$. Therefore, there are two solutions: $(x,y)=(2,3)$ and $(x,y)=(-2,-3)$. In other words, the square roots of $-5+12i$ are $2+3i$ and $-2-3i$.

Comment: +1 Nice trick. It's Bendit, by the way. :-)

Comment: @TheoBendit: edited

Comment: @Taladris: thanks a lot~

Answer (score 1):

(b) From the two equations provided, we have $y = \frac{6}{x}$ (note that $x \neq 0$), and hence
$$x^2 - \frac{36}{x^2} = -5 \implies x^4 - 36 = -5x^2.$$
This is a quadratic in $x^2$, which is straight forward to solve. Bear in mind, $x$ is assumed to be a real number, so feel free to reject any non-real solutions (mind you, after you find $y$ and express it as $x + iy$, the non-real solutions should come out the same anyway).

(d) You already found the roots $\pm z$ of $-5 + 12i$. That is, you found $\pm z$ such that $(\pm z)^2 = -5 + 12i$. If you look at the conjugate of these square roots, you'll have
$$(\pm \overline{z})^2 = \overline{(\pm z)^2} = \overline{-5 + 12i} = -5 - 12i.$$
That is, the two square roots of $-5 - 12i$ are simply the conjugates of the square roots found in part (b).

Comment: Understand! Thanks for you answer!!