# Is this the only way to evaluate $\sqrt{2i-1}?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

work out the $\sqrt{2i-1}?$

$2i-1=(a+bi)^2$

$a^2+2abi-b^2$

$a^2-b^2=-1$

$2ab=2$

---

$a^2=b^{-2}$

$b^{-2}-b^2=-1$

$-b^{4}+1=-1$

$b^4=2$

$b=\sqrt[4]{2}$

Can we solve $\sqrt{2i-1}$ in another way?

Comment: Do you know any field/Galois theory? The tools it provides are really nice for problems like these. Other than that, I don't see why this is a bad approach.

Comment: No i don't, can you show it

Comment: It's not something really that I can show just as is. You need a bit of background to take on that material. In that case, what you've done is more than fine.

Comment: You made a mistake going from $b^{-2}-b^2=-1$ to $-b^4+1=-1$. It should be $-b^4+1=-b^2$.

Comment: Please search up how to convert a complex number to its polar form and the DeMoivre's Theorem.

Comment: The square root has 2 solutions.  You need to get them both.

Comment: @DonThousand could you please write an answer with the tools you mentioned? The answer will be a good starting point to learn more about the tools (for me at least)

Comment: @user1952500 At some point, sure.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number

Answer (score 1):

I am using polar coordinates.

> In short, the polar or trigonometric form of the complex number $z=a+bi$ is $z=r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$. Here, $r=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and $\theta = \tan^{-1}{\frac ba}$ for $a>0$ or $\theta = \tan^{-1}{\frac ba + \pi}$ for $a<0$.

Converting $2i-1$ to polar form, you get $z=\sqrt 5(\cos(\tan^{-1}-2 + \pi) + i\sin(\tan^{-1}-2 + \pi)).$

> DeMoivre's theorem states that for a positive integer $p$, the complex number $r(\cos\theta + i\sin\theta)$ has $p$ distinct $p$th roots. They are found by $$r^{\frac1p}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi n}p\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\theta+2\pi n}p\right)\right)$$$n = 0,1,2,...,p-1$

Here, $n=2$ (square root). I think you know how to proceed. Remember to calculate for both roots.