# How should I calculate the square root of a complex number using a Casio 991EX?

Tags: radicals, calculator

With Casio 991EX how should I calculate the square root of a complex number? It says Math error even though is set in COMPLEX mode

Comment: Related: [How do I get the square root of a complex number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number?rq=1).  Rather than solely relying on technology, learning how to do it manually is an important skill.

Answer (score 2):

If the calculator does not support complex square roots natively, you can

- convert from Cartesian to polar,
- divide the argument by two,
- square-root the modulus,
- convert back to Cartesian.

---

Alternatively, if there is no conversion,

$$(a+ib)^2=x+iy\iff\begin{cases}a^2-b^2=x,\\2ab=y\end{cases}.$$

Then

$$a^4-a^2b^2=a^4-\frac{y^2}4=xa^2$$ is a biquadratic equation in $a$, giving

$$a=\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2},\\ b=\frac y{2a}.$$

Answer (score 0):

For $a\neq 0$,

$$\sqrt{a+ib}=\pm\sqrt[4]{a^2+b^2}\left[\cos\frac{\left(\arctan\frac b{a}\right)}2+i\sin\frac{\left(\arctan\frac b{a}\right)}2\right]$$

If $a=0$,
$$\sqrt{ib}=\pm\frac{\sqrt{2|b|}}2(1\pm i)$$
where the sign of $i$ is the same as of $b$.