# Find the complex square root of $7+6\sqrt2i$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the complex square root of 
>   $$7+6\sqrt2i$$
>   giving your answer in the form $x+iy$ where $x$ and $y$ are real.

The answer I have gotten is $-23+84\sqrt2i$
by squaring $7+6\sqrt2i$,
but the “correct” answer is $\pm(3+i\sqrt2)$.

Can you explain how I got this wrong?

Comment: You are interested in square root, not square right?

Comment: If you use curly brackets `{2}` instead of regular brackets, $\sqrt{2}$ renders correctly. In fact, since $2$ is a single digit, you don't really need brackets at all: `\sqrt 2` works just fine.

Comment: Hello everybody, before adding yet another answer explaining how to find complex square roots in general, which has been done many times already one this site ([canonical question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44406/how-do-i-get-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number)), notice that the actual question is “Can you explain how I got this wrong?”. And this is answered in the first comment above (which should have been an answer)...

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267156/find-the-square-root-of-a-complex-number) is another question asking for square roots of a complex number

Answer (score 3):

The fast way to obtain square roots of complex numbers is this: by identification of $(x+iy)^2$ with the given number, you obtain the *non-linear* system
\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2=7,\\
xy=3\sqrt 2.
\end{cases}
You may add the relation deduced from comparing $|x+iy|^2$ with  the given number modulus:
$$x^2+y^2=\sqrt{49+72}=11,$$
so that you obtain a very simple *linear* system in $x^2$ and $y^2$:
\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2=7,\\
x^2+y^2=11.
\end{cases}
You can solve this system and  deduce the values of $x$ and $y$, using the third equation, which implies that $x$ and $y$ have the same sign.

Answer (score 2):

A different method for rendering complex square roots with non-real radicands is what I call "the angle bisection method", from a familiar geometric construction.

Render

$(z+|z|)^2=z^2+2z|z|+|z|^2=z^2+2z|z|+z\overline{z}$

$=2z|z|+2z(z+\overline{z})$

$\color{blue}{=2z(|z|+\Re(z))}$

So, upon taking square roots and solving:

$\sqrt z=\pm(z+|z|)/\sqrt{2(|z|+\Re(z))}$

Note the denominator is real, so the real and imaginary parts are automatically resolved.  Here $|z|=11$ is rational, allowing a simplified form for the square root.  We directly get, as given in other answers, $\pm (3+\sqrt 2i)$.

Comment: nice method for complex square roots (+1), but may need some editing:  did you mean $2z(z\color{red}+ \bar z)$?  also, you didn't have a division sign to indicate the radical in the *denominator*

Comment: Yup, typos are a major issue when working on a mobile device.  So is trying to answer when you are up at 5 am for a workout!

Answer (score 1):

Let  square roots of $7+6\sqrt{2}i $ be $\pm(a+bi);$ squaring this we have $a^2-b^2+2abi=7+6\sqrt{2}i;$ comparing coefficients we have $a^2-b^2=7,ab=3\sqrt{2};$ substituting for $b$ in the first equation we have $a^2-\frac{18}{a^2}=7;$ multiplying throughout by $a^2$ and rearranging we get $a^4-18-7a^2=a^4+2a^2-9a^2-18=a^2(a^2+2)-9(a^2+2)=(a^2-9)(a^2+2)=0$ thus $a=\pm 3$ (as $a$ is a real number in our assumption we rule out the second case, i.e., $a=\pm \sqrt{2}i)$ now finding out $b=\pm \sqrt{2}$. Thus the square roots are $\pm(3+\sqrt{2}i)$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sqrt{7+6\sqrt2i}=\sqrt{9+6\sqrt2i+(\sqrt2i)^2}=\sqrt{(3+\sqrt2i)^2}=\{3+\sqrt2i,-3-\sqrt2i\}.$$
By the way, $$(-23+84\sqrt2i)^2\neq7+6\sqrt2i.$$

Maybe you calculated $(7+6\sqrt2i)^2$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $z = x + yi$ is a complex number where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, and let $\theta = \arg(z) \in [0,2\pi] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. The square root

$$\begin{aligned}
\sqrt{z} &= \sqrt{r\cos \theta + ir\sin \theta} = \sqrt{r}\cos \frac{\theta}{2} + i\sqrt{r}\sin \frac{\theta}{2} \\
&= \sqrt{r}\sqrt{\frac{1 + \cos \theta}{2}} + i\sqrt{r}\sqrt{\frac{1 - \cos \theta}{2}} \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{|z| + \Re(z)}{2}} + i\sqrt{\frac{|z| - \Re(z)}{2}}.
\end{aligned}$$

Hence $$\sqrt{7 + i6\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{11 + 7}{2}} + i\sqrt{\frac{11 - 7}{2}} = 3 + i\sqrt{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to convert to polar form and then use De Moivre, but the way the question is framed seems to want you to do it the straightforward way, namely square $x+iy$ and equate it to $7+6\sqrt 2 i,$ which yields the $2×2$ quadratic system $$x^2-y^2=7, 2xy=6\sqrt 2.$$ Since both $\text{LHS}$ are homogeneous of order two, a substitution will yield a biquadratic either in $x$ or $y,$ which is easily solved.