# understanding complex roots

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I have problem in understanding the meaning of complex roots. If I have the following term:
\begin{align}
\lambda^2 = k^2 + i\frac{x}{y}
\end{align}
with $k$ being a complex number and $x,y\in \mathbb{R}_+$. I know that I now have two solutions, $-\lambda$ and $+\lambda$. But how do I compute them?

Somebody told me, that if I set Re$(\lambda)>0$, that this would define which of the two square roots is called $\lambda$ and which $-\lambda$. What does this mean?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1758902) & [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number).