# Find Imaginary and real part

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

Find out the imaginary and real parts, simple multiplications, but confused in the roots. Can any one give proper solution for it.

$$(\sqrt{3} + 2\sqrt{i})(3\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{i})$$

[This is how much I solved !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjE9M.jpg)

Comment: The number $3+2i$ has two square roots. Which one do you have in mind?

Comment: @NaDimKhAn: try to use the MathJax to avoid any confusion in your questions.

Comment: The square root in on individuals @JoséCarlosSantos not on both, someone edited the question

Comment: How @Amin, its just a javascript library

Comment: @NaDimKhAn: Check this page. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @NaDimKhAn Then revert that edition.

Comment: check it now @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @NaDimKhAn It's clear now. Why don't you do multiplication? It's so easy.

Comment: I can multiply , i have solved some questions, but i am confused when the multiplication goes down to the roots

Comment: @NaDimKhAn Please say what did you get and I (or someone else) will tell you if that's right or wrong.

Comment: ok, just simply answer me what will i get when i multiply, (2i)(3√3) & (2i)(2√i)

Comment: You know, it's not so nice to demand from people to answer you, whatever your question is. José has been kind enough to offer some hints and has asked you politely to show your own work, so that he may point you in the right direction.

Comment: let me post a pic

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/what-is-sqrti) should help

Comment: I was actually working on a partial answer for this, but after reading through the comments, I have deleted the draft in opposition to @NaDimKhAn’s demand

Comment: Have a look at the picture, @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: Isn't there a typo, $3\sqrt3+\sqrt2 i$ instead ?

Comment: yes have a look @YvesDaoust

Comment: Not more believable.

Comment: "ok, just simply answer me what will i get when i multiply, (2i)(3√3) & (2i)(2√i)".  You can $(6\sqrt{3})i$ for the first one and $4i\sqrt{i}$ for the second.  However $\sqrt{i}$ is ambiguous and has two possible answers.  Do you know how to find the two possible $(a + bi)$ where $(a+bi)^2 = i$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(\sqrt{3} + 2\sqrt{i})(3\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{i})=$

$\sqrt{3}*3\sqrt{3} + 2\sqrt{i}*3\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{3}*2\sqrt{i} + 2\sqrt{i}*2\sqrt{i} = $.

$9\sqrt{3} + 6*\sqrt{3}*\sqrt{i} + 2*\sqrt{3}\sqrt{i} + 4*\sqrt{i}^2$ =

$= 9\sqrt{3} + 8\sqrt{3}\sqrt{i} + 4i$

Now we need to know what $\sqrt{i}$ is.  Have you learned that?

Now I must make an editorial comment.  $\sqrt{i}$ is very badly written.  All non-zero complex or real numbers have two square roots and it is not at all clear which one is meant.

Let $(a+bi)^2 = a^2 + 2abi + b^2i^2 = (a^2 -b^2) + 2abi = i$.

So $a^2 - b^2 = 0$ and $2ab = 1$ and $a,b \in \mathbb R$.  Can you solve this?

$a^2 = b^2$ and $2ab = 1$.

$a + bi = \sqrt{i}$ and there are *two* solutions.  And in this case it is unclear which one they want.

So solve for $\sqrt{i}$ and plug it in.

You will have two possible answers.