# Why is $\sqrt{-i} = -(-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

I was doing some research to look for fun on the properties of $i$, the square root of $-1$, and it got me thinking about what the square root of $-i$ was, or the square root of $-1$.  I found on wolfram alpha that it is $\sqrt{-i} = -(-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}$
, but I can't find an explanation anywhere.  Can someone help me?

Comment: The Wolfram-alpha answer doesn't give you any extra knowledge on the nature of sqrt(-i).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3315

Comment: @AndrewLi That question is different, it'm asking about the _negative_ square root of i, not just the positive square root of i.

Comment: wolframalpha actually says $\sqrt{-i}=-(-1)^{\frac{3}{4}}$. you must have made a typo

Comment: Made the edit, it was a typo.

Comment: Every nonzero complex number has two square roots, and four fourth roots.

Comment: Be careful with $\sqrt{{}\cdot{}}$ and fractional exponents when the base is negative or complex. They are multivalued, and comparing different expressions with $=$ is precarious. With a calculator like WolframAlpha you never know which of the multiple values it's going to pick. I'd stay clear of it all together, personally, work with integer exponents as much as possible. Instead of $\sqrt i$, use "a solution to $x^2=i$", and so on.

Comment: btw. the typo is still there (the inline equation, not the title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard is to define the principal argument of a complex number as
$$
 - \pi  < {\rm Arg}\left( z \right) \le \pi 
$$
and not from $0$ to $2\pi$.
And all modern CAS respect this convention, and give the results of calculations with complex numbers , square root in particular, as the [**principal value**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value) , i.e. with the argument in that range.
That by default, unless of course proper options are activated.

Therefore, always reducing to the *principal value*, we have
$$
 - i = e^{\, - i\,\pi /2} 
$$
thus
$$
\sqrt { - i}  = e^{\, - i\,\pi /4} 
$$
and on the other hand
$$
 - \left( { - 1} \right)^{3/4}  =  - \left( {e^{\,\,i\,\pi } } \right)^{3/4}  =  - e^{\,\,i3/4\,\pi }  = e^{\,\,i\,\pi } e^{\,\,i3/4\,\pi }  = e^{\,\,i7/4\,\pi }  \to e^{\, - i\,\pi /4} 
$$

Answer (score 1):

If two complex numbers are equal, if a+ bi= c+ di then the real and imaginary parts are equal, a= c and b= d.  That is part of the **definition** of the "a+ bi" notation.  Her you have $A^2- B^2+ 2ABi= 0+ i$.  You must have the real parts $A^2- B^2= 0$ and imaginary part 2AB= 1.

Personally I would have used the "polar form".  $-i= e^{3\pi/2}$.  The square root of that is $e^{3\pi/4}$.  On the other hand, $-1= e^{i\pi}$ so that $(-1)^{3/4}= e^{3i\pi/4}$.

Comment: Can you explain polar form for me?

Comment: note that the standard convention is $-i=e^{-i\pi/2}$: see my answer above.