# Questioning the commutative property in complex powers

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

We have:$$e^{2\pi\cdot i(1+\frac{1}{x})}$$

Power properties state that: $a^{b\cdot c}=(a^{b})^{c}=(a^{c})^{b}$. Thus we could re-write the above power as:
$$(e^{2\pi\cdot i})^{1+\frac{1}{x}}=1$$
Which should be equal to:
$$(e^{1+\frac{1}{x}})^{2\pi\cdot i}\neq1$$
But this is not the case. Also the first result is a Real number while the second is a Complex one.

I'm not really questioning anything, I just couldn't find the right title. Can anyone explain me where the mistake is?

Comment: totally didn't see it. Thanks

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2914, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2903.