# funny complex equality 1 = -1

Tags: complex-numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$i^2$ why is it $-1$ when you can show it is $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1)

Try to find what's wrong there:
nb: the squareroot can be defined for all complex numbers as $\exp(1/2\cdot\log(z))$

$$1 = \sqrt 1 = \sqrt{-1\cdot-1} = \sqrt{i^2\cdot i^2} = \sqrt{i}^2 \cdot\sqrt{i}^2 = i \cdot i = -1 $$

edit:
$ \sqrt{i} = \exp(1/2\cdot\log(i)) $

to find $\log(i)$:
$$\begin{align}
&x+iy = \log(i)\\
&\exp(x)\exp(iy) = i\\
&\exp(x)\exp(iy) = i\\
&\exp(x)(\cos(y)+i\sin(y)) = i
\end{align}$$
we arrive at $y=\pi/2$ and $x=0$

so  $ \sqrt{i} = \exp(1/2\cdot i\cdot\pi/2)  $

and $ \sqrt{i}^2 = i  $

where are the multiple values?

Comment: Square root of complex number is multiple-valued

Comment: could you reopen the question, the said duplicates are not

Comment: The answer to why the derivation of $1=-1$ is invalid yet seemingly legitimate is the very topic of, and is exposed in the responses to, the linked question. Your edit includes some equations and "where are the multiple values?" -- is this supposed to be interpreted by others as a distinct question of sorts? Trying my best to make sense of it, I imagine you're looking for an adaptation of the original false proof to (invalidly) find multiple values again for $\sqrt{i}^2$. If so, you should always ask separate questions as separate questions.

Comment: well had to search far in the answers, gary's answer seems good, tx