# How can I solve this para Paradox?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs, paradoxes

How can I solve this para Paradox?

$ -1={(-1)}^{1/2} {(-1)}^{1/2}={[(-1)(-1)]}^{1/2}=1$

Comment: Bound to be a duplicate, but your middle equality is unjustified for complex numbers

Comment: or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/simple-complex-number-problem-1-1

Comment: or http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144363/funny-complex-equality-1-1?lq=1 or many more