# $1 +1$ is $0$ ?​

Tags: arithmetic, fake-proofs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [-1 is not 1, so where is the mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/1-is-not-1-so-where-is-the-mistake)
>   [$i^2$ why is it $-1$ when you can show it is $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1)

So:

$$
\begin{align}
    1+1 &= 1 + \sqrt{1} \\
    &= 1 + \sqrt{1 \times 1} \\
    &= 1 + \sqrt{-1 \times -1} \\
    &= 1 + \sqrt{-1} \times \sqrt{-1} \\
    &= 1 + i \times i \\
    &= 1 + (-1) \\
    &= 1 - 1\\
    &= 0
  \end{align}
$$

I can't see anything wrong there, and I can't see anything wrong in $1+1=2$ too. Clearly, $1+1$ is $2$, but I really want to know where is the incorrect part in the above.

Comment: You cannot do this operation with complex numbers!

Comment: As has been pointed out the error lies in the step that asserts that $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = (\sqrt{-1})(\sqrt{-1})$. This identity does not hold for nonnegative factors. Perhaps someone can find the duplicates.

Comment: Perhaps it was "for non-positive or zero factors..."?

Comment: Note that 1+1=0 mod 2, in which case every equality in the post can be interpreted as a true statement (we can take $i=1$ in this context). This shows that the error in the argument is not intrinsic to the algebra, but depends on properties of the ground field/context in which the equations are set.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{b}$$ is valid only for non-negative real numbers $a$ and $b$. Hence, the error is in the step $$\sqrt{(-1) \times (-1)} = \sqrt{-1} \times \sqrt{-1}$$

Comment: Why is it only valid for non-negative numbers?

Comment: @Derek $\sqrt x$ is by definition the positive square root of $x$ and is only defined for $x\ge0$. The symbol $\sqrt{-1}$ is an abuse of notation in fact. The definition of $i$ is $i^2 = -1$

Comment: @Derek: because you get a contradiction otherwise? In the complex numbers it's only valid when $a,b$ have arguments in $[0,\pi)$ due to the standard branch cut. (Technically I think exactly one of $a,b$ may also have argument $\pi$, i.e. be on the negative real axis).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot split the square root term since that is only valid for non-negative numbers.

$$\sqrt{-1 \cdot -1} \ne \sqrt{-1}\cdot  \sqrt{-1}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have that $\sqrt{-1} \times \sqrt{-1} = (\sqrt{-1})^{2} = -1$ but $\sqrt{-1 \times -1} = \sqrt{1} = 1$. So $\sqrt{-1 \times -1} \neq \sqrt{-1} \times \sqrt{-1}$ which is the error.