# Arithmetic question regarding $\sqrt{1/-1} = \sqrt{-1/1}$

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [-1 is not 1, so where is the mistake?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/1-is-not-1-so-where-is-the-mistake)
>   [$i^2$ why is it $-1$ when you can show it is $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1)

Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong here?

$$ \frac{1}{-1} = \frac{-1}{1} \implies \sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}} = \sqrt{\frac{-1}{1}} $$
which should imply that
$$ \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}} = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{1}} $$

But the last equality is not true. Is there something really obvious that I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Square roots behave slightly differently on complex numbers. This has been covered on the site before.

Comment: The issue is that $\sqrt{ab}\neq \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$. This question has been asked here before in numerous variations.

Comment: $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ only holds when $a, b \ge 0.$ Hence $\sqrt{\frac{1}{-1}} \neq \frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}.$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f \colon A \to B$ is a given function. From $x=y$ you can get $f(x)=f(y)$, but **only** when $x$ and $y$ belong to $A$. In your example, $f=\sqrt{\cdot}$, $A=[0,+\infty)$ and $B=\mathbb{R}$. But $x=-1/1 = -1 \notin A$, and you can't conclude.

Of course, you may say that $A =\mathbb{C}$, but then $f$ becomes multi-valued.