# Starting with $\frac{-1}{1}=\frac{1}{-1}$ and taking square root: proves $1=-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, fake-proofs

In this [blog post](http://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2013/05/15/graduate-student-traps/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter), RJ. Lipton mentions an example of common mathematical traps. In particular, that ``square root is not a function''. He shows the following trap:

Start with:
$\frac{-1}{1}=\frac{1}{-1}$, then take the square root of both sides:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{1}}=\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}
$$
hence
$$
\frac{i}{1} = \frac{1}{i} \\
i^2=1 \enspace ,
$$
which contradicts the definition that $i^2=-1$.

Question 1: I know that the square root is not a function because it is multi-valued, but I still can not wrap my head around this example. Where was the problem exactly? Was is that we

- can not convert $\sqrt{1/-1}$ to $\sqrt{1}/\sqrt{-1}$?
- both the RHS and LHS are *unordered* sets?
- both?

Question 2: Also, does this problem only arise in equalities or in general algebraic manipulation? Because it would be a nightmare when manipulating an expression with fractional powers! Are there easy rules to determine what is safe to do with fractional powers? To see what I mean, there is another [example](http://mrhonner.com/2011/08/11/are-these-tests-any-good-part-1/) of a similar trap:

One might easily think that $\sqrt[4]{16x^2y^7}$ is equivalent to $2x^{1/2}y^{7/4}$, which is not true for $x=-1$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445585/what-are-some-common-pitfalls-when-squaring-both-sides-of-an-equation?rq=1 .

Comment: The condition that you need is that the base of all exponents are non-negative.

Comment: Where the question is "can not convert...", the answer is *no* . With a little complex analysis is reasonably simple to explain this by means of branches, multivalued function and stuff. The fact is that the rules of exponents can be applied *only* to non-negative reals...for the time being.

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/185502/264

Comment: @ZevChonoles : The first question yes. But not the second question.

Comment: Here's another "proof": $-1 = \sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{(-1)\cdot(-1)} = \sqrt{1} = 1$. And to debunk the misconception that this type of wrong reasoning is somehow special to square roots of negative quantities, here's one that "works" completely in the real numbers: $-1 = (-1)^1 = (-1)^{2\cdot\frac12} = ((-1)^2)^{\frac12} = \sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without going into complex analysis, I think this is the simplest way I can explain this. Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Note that the (maximal) domain of $f$ is the set of all non-negative numbers. And how is this defined? $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ is equal to a non-negative number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. In this sense, square root is a function! It is called the **principal square root**.

In contrast, the following correspondence is not a function: the relation $g$ takes in a value $x$ and returns a value $y$ such that $y^2=x$. For example, under $g$, 1 corresponds to two values, $1,-1$.

Now, the property of distributing a square root over a product is only proven (at least in precalculus) over the domain of the principal square root, that is, only for non-negative numbers. Given this, there is **no basis** for the step

$$\frac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}} = \frac{\sqrt{-1}}{\sqrt{1}}.$$

As to why this property is not true, the best explanation for now is that because $-1$ is not in the domain of the principal square root. Hence, $\sqrt{-1}$ does not actually make sense, as far as our definition of square root is concerned. In complex analysis, more can be said. As a commenter mentioned, this has something to do with branches of logarithms.

For your second question, I think it is safe that you always keep in mind what the domain of the function is. If you will get a negative number inside an even root, then you can't distribute the even root over products or quotients.

Comment: And by the way, one rule you can keep in mind is that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Comment: So is it *always* safe to distribute the root over products and quotients if ["the number insider the root is positive" $\vee$ "the root is odd"]? Is that the rule?

Comment: Yes, that would be the rule. :)

Comment: But in this example, $e$, the base of the natural logarithm, is positive:    $e^{z} \overset{!}{=} (e^{2\pi i})^{z/2\pi i} = 1^{z/2\pi i} = 1$ for all $z$. Is this an exception to the rule?

Comment: @M.Alaggan: the thing you're doing there is not "distributing the root over a product or a quotient". Transforming $(ab)^c$ to $a^cb^c$ is distributing a root over a product (when $c$ is the reciprocal of an integer). That's not the same as transforming $a^{(bc)}$ to $(a^b)^c$, which is what you're doing here.

Answer (score 2):

at real analysis

$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}\ = \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}}$$

only for $y,x>0$

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the conversion of:
$$\sqrt{\frac{x}{y}}\ \to \ \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{y}}$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on why is this a problem?