# Clarification on the Property of a complex number

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$i^2$ why is it $-1$ when you can show it is $1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1)

Consider the set of complex numbers.
Does the equation
$ \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-1}$ holds? Why?

Comment: How do you define $\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: If you define $\sqrt{x}$ as a single valued function on complex numbers, it cannot be defined so that $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$, only so that $\sqrt{xy} = \pm \sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The question is not 'Why does this equation fail to hold?' - it is 'Why should this be true?'. We can *prove* that $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$ when at most one of $x,y$ is negative, but not when both are.