# Math complex numbers.

Tags: complex-numbers

I have heard that $i=\sqrt{-1}$ and I have also read about it here http://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/imaginary-numbers.html.

Now I want to ask why in example $\sqrt{-4} = 2i$ as $i=\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: possible duplicate

Comment: Where is the duplicated question please?

Comment: I do not recall the exact one, but this is similar question that has all the answer you might seek. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1

Comment: $\sqrt{-4}$ are the complex numbers $x$ that satisfy $x^2=-4$. Thus  $x=2i$ or $x=-2i$.

Comment: @StefanHansen also x = -2i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because $(2i)^2 = 2^2 i^2 = 4 \cdot -1 = -4$. Thus $2i$ is a possible answer to $\sqrt{-4}$ (though perhaps not the only one. What about $-2i$?)

Comment: Ok. Thank @mixedmath I understood now.

Answer (score 2):

If you remember the basic definition

$$x=\sqrt a\Longleftrightarrow x^2=a $$

then

$$(2i)^2=2^2i^2=-4\Longleftrightarrow\sqrt{-4}=2i$$

Of course, also $\,(-2i)\,$ makes the job.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is correct. But I accepted @mixedmath answer. He was first.

Comment: You don't need to explain your decision as one chooses whatever answer seems better, but I thank you for doing it.

Comment: You're being a bit careless with the equivalence arrows here, since also $x=-\sqrt{a}$ satisfies $x^2=a$...