# Contradiction involving the (in)equality between an absolute value and it's negation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

The above is my 'proof' of two statements involving $|x|.$ Since they clearly contradict each other, where I have gone wrong in the proof?

Comment: Statement 2 is wrong: $-\vert x \vert = -(x^2)^{1/2} \ne (x^2)^{1/2}$.

Comment: See [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717882/how-does-the-exponent-of-a-function-effect-the-result), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-cdot-1-neq-sqrt-12), [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1628759/what-are-the-laws-of-rational-exponents/1640048).

Answer (score 1):

Statement 2 is false: the 9th and 13th equalities in your work are false. Those two steps collectively *falsely* assume that $$y=(y^2)^{\frac12}\iff y\in\mathbb R.$$ In actuality, $$y=(y^2)^{\frac12}\iff y\ge0\\
-y=(y^2)^{\frac12}\iff y\le0.$$

[image]