# What is wrong with this proof of $i = 0$?

Tags: fake-proofs

This is a proof I made a year ago and at that time, I didn't see any problems with it. Could anyone point out what is wrong here?

> Consider the following expresion: $(-1)^{(4n+3)/2}$, where $n \in \Bbb Z_+$. We have that:
>   \begin{align}
> (-1)^{(4n+3)/2} &= [(-1)^{4n+3}]^{1/2} = (-1)^{1/2} = i \\
> (-1)^{(4n+3)/2} &= [(-1)^{1/2}]^{4n+3} = i^{4n+3} = -i
> \end{align}
>   That means $i=-i$ $\implies$ $i=0$.

Comment: why do you say $i=-i$?

Comment: Sophisticated version of $-1=\sqrt 1=1$

Comment: Why do you think $(-1)^{1/2} = i$? This expression has two values, $\pm i$.

Comment: Multivalued functions require a defined branch cut.

Comment: Similar (if not duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472227/math-fallacy-problem-1-13-16-2-sqrt-16-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'square root' is not a function in complex numbers - there are two distinct values of $\sqrt{-1},$ and if you take the other one, which is $-i$, the result would be $-i=-i.$