# What is the mistake I'm making with simplifying powers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I came across an issue when I tried to simplify an expression, like this:
$$(-1)^{2x}=((-1)^2)^x=(1)^x=1$$
So now it looks like the expression I started with will always equal one. However, when I for example fill in $x=\frac{1}{2}$, I get this:
$$(-1)^{2x}=(-1)^{2\cdot\frac{1}{2}}=(-1)^1=-1$$
It clearly does not equal one, so I made a mistake somewhere. Apparently the first step, $(-1)^{2x}=((-1)^2)^x$, is only true when $x$ is even. Why is this?

I thought maybe the rule does not apply if the base number is negative. But that would not explain why you get the same error when simplifying this:
$$e^{2x\pi i}=(e^{2\pi i})^x=(1)^x=1$$
Again, if you fill in a half, the result should be -1 and not 1.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3219025/why-22-5-isnt-equal-to-2251-10):    fractional powers of negative numbers are not uniquely defined, and the "general rule" $(a^m)^n=a^{m×n}$ does not always work when $m$ and $n$ are not integers

Comment: See also [math fallacy problem: $-1= (-1)^3 = (-1)^{6/2} = \sqrt{(-1)^6}= 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472227/math-fallacy-problem-1-13-16-2-sqrt-16-1).