# Proof that $\sqrt{x}=-\sqrt{x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

$\sqrt{x}=\sqrt{1\cdot x}=\sqrt{(-1)^2\cdot x} = \sqrt{(-1)^2} \cdot \sqrt{x} = (-1) \cdot \sqrt{x}=-\sqrt{x}$

The idea popped into my head while I was evaluating an integral. I have a feeling that I made some obvious mistake because the "proof" is so simple, but I don't see any flaw. Of course, there must be a flaw somewhere. What is it?

Comment: You seem to be using the false statement $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=-1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think this should be marked as a duplicate of your given question; this one seems to show confusion about the fact that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ rather than the fact that the identity $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ does not always hold whenever $a,b\in\mathbb C$.

Comment: @mathh: There are duplicates regarding that issue as well. But this "idea" is based on the notion that $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{-1}^2$, which is what happens in the suggested duplicate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila It is my opinion that we should help the question askers with the exact problems they have. I highly doubt the OP thought of it as $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$ rather than $\sqrt{a^2}=a$. The question you've pointed to wouldn't show the OP that $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ and hence he would stay baffled about it.

Comment: I agree with @mathh, this question is based on a different conceptual error than the one linked to.  See my comment on kang zhou's answer below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most fake proofs involving square roots rest, at some point, on the false identity
$$\sqrt{a^2} = a$$
This identity seems natural and true, which is why it fools us.  The correct identity is
$$\sqrt{a^2} = |a|$$

Comment: The question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/i2-why-is-it-1-when-you-can-show-it-is-1 shows confusion about $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$. The fallacy given there doesn't rely on $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ (which disproves your point that every fake proof rests on the false identity).

Comment: I didn't say "every", I said "most".  Surely you recognize the difference?

Comment: Sorry for that.

Comment: (Here it is assumed $a$ is real.)

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} = \sqrt 1 = 1 \neq -1$$

Perhaps you are making the mistake of thinking $(\sqrt{(-1)^2} = (-1)^{2/2} = (-1)^{1} = -1$, but this too is mistaken because $(-1)^{1/2}$ does not exist in the real numbers, so $\Big((-1)^{1/2}\Big)^2$ does not exist, whereas $\Big((-1)^{2}\Big)^{1/2} = 1$ *does* indeed exist.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{(-1)^2 \cdot x}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}\cdot \sqrt{x}$and $\sqrt{(-1)^2}=-1$ are wrong.

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: Agree with @GitGud, which is precisely why I think this question is *not* a duplicate of the one people are linking to; that question incorrectly uses $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ while this question *correctly* uses it.

Comment: $\sqrt{(-1)^2 \cdot (-5)}=\sqrt{(-1)^2} \cdot \sqrt{-5}$ is right?!!

Comment: I remember that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ is right only for $a,b \geq 0$.

Comment: The first equality is correct assuming that both radicands are real and positive; note that nowhere in the OP are square roots of negative quantities involved.