# 1 = -1 Clearest way to explain why this proof is wrong.

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs, proof-explanation

Say you are a high school student or a young undergrad. You are being taught about complex numbers and you are told that $i = \sqrt{-1}$.

You go home and you write this:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
1 & = 1 \\
1 & = \sqrt{1} \\
1 & = \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} \\
1 & = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} \\
1 & = i \times i \\
1 & = i^2 \\
1 & = -1
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

You are dismayed. The infamous imaginary numbers are inconsistent after all!

---

The best answer would be the clearest explanation of why the "proof" is faulty, keeping in mind the level of the student. An explanation is extra clear if t presents insights to the student, as well as being correct and concise.

Comment: Who says you can do the step $1=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} $ ?

Comment: $$\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}\ne\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}$$

Comment: I am guessing the OP wants a clear explanation of why multiplication and taking the root doesn't commute for $-1$.

Comment: **I think this is not a duplicate.** Aparently, the OP knows at least one 'proof' of this. He's not asking "why" is the proof faulty, he's asking for a clear and easy explanaton of this fact for a particular public: school students. For example, the property $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ can be a little bit tough to school students, let alone non-intuitive.

Comment: I think the real issue, which is unfortunately embedded deeply in our pedagogy, is the notation. Instead of a functional (though not unique) characterisation ($i^2 = -1$), we have the appealing $\sqrt{-1}$ which comes with many pitfalls.

Comment: @SolidSnake Thanks for defending the question: you understood the spirit. Unfortunately it is now closed. I would have liked to see what Physics SE users would have come up with.

Comment: I must admit however, that the accepted answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12 would have been a perfect answer to this question too.

Comment: Explain slowly and carefully that $\sqrt{a*b} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ isn't true *not even for real numbers* (as in real numbers the square root of negative numbers is undefined) and that *every* time you've done it in the past you've assumed both terms were positive.

Comment: I think this should be reopened (possibly with 'high school' in the title :-)) as the issue is about explaining the fallacy at that level.

Answer (score 4):

A priori, $\sqrt{-1}$ is just notation for some new object which, when squared, yields $-1$. It is not some operator $\sqrt{}$ applied to the number $-1$. There is no reason one should expect it to behave exactly like the traditional square root function, which isn't defined for negative numbers.

Comment: "a priori" will go over really well, with your typical high school student.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

$$ \sqrt{(-1)(-1)} \neq \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1} $$

---

One way to see this is to use the property $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so that

$$ \sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=|-1|=1. $$

Only for non-negative $x$ and $y$ is it true that $\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{y}$.

Comment: But then the student would think $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ for complex. $i = \sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{I^2} = |i| = 1$ so $-1 = i^2 = 1^ = 1$.  We're no better off.

Comment: I mention in the answer that $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ holds for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, so I don't understand the confusion.

Comment: Think of it from a student's point of view.  We are throwing all these definitions at him/her and suddenly saying they only work when we want them to.  $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ is specifically brought up to point out that $\sqrt {x^2} \ne x$.  And we seem to be bringing it up to show that $\sqrt{ab} \ne \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ (I presume because ... well, I'm not sure why) And then we are saying that somehow because a rule  works in the reals an entirely different rule won't work another way in the complex.  It doesn't really held the student understand the fault in the proof.

Comment: @fleablood A conceptual question requires a conceptual answer. If you have an answer that does not use the properties I used I think we would all be better off if you devoted your energy to submitting it as an alternative. I'm not doubting you, I just don't see the point of what you are saying if you don't have an alternative.