# Why is $i^3$ (the complex number "$i$") equal to $-i$ instead of $i$?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

$$i^3=iii=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{(-1)(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}=i
$$

Please take a look at the equation above. What am I doing wrong to understand $i^3 = i$, not $-i$?

Comment: $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ is only guaranteed for positive reals.

Comment: The third equal in your equation is not right. Please refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Notes

Comment: Isn't it simpler that that? i^3 is i * i * i. i * i = -1 -1 * i = -i Isn't that all there is to it? doug

Comment: The notation $\sqrt{a}$ is only well-defined (single-valued) for real, non-negative $a$ (unless you choose some [principal value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number)). Try to use $\pm\sqrt{a}$ much more than $\sqrt{a}$. It is still true that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\pm\sqrt{ab}$ for complex numbers.

Comment: There are so many duplicates of this : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/simple-complex-number-problem-1-1 http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/simple-complex-number-problem-1-1 . Why dont you search before asking and what are the moderators doing , sigh !

Comment: @Trafalgar Law, I am very very sorry for what I did :( I hope you forgive me.

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw: more constructive, [and friendly](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/behavior), might be to suggest how to search for this topic. Often knowing what to search for is not obvious.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

We cannot say that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ for negative $a$ and $b$. If this were true, then $1=\sqrt{1}=\sqrt{\left(-1\right)\cdot\left(-1\right)} = \sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=i\cdot i=-1$. Since this is false, we have to say that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}\neq\sqrt{ab}$ in general when we extend it to accept negative numbers.

Answer (score 56):

Since $i^2=-1$ by definition, $i^3=i^2\cdot i=-i$.

$\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ is only guaranteed for positive real $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 32):

I'm sure everyone has answered the question appropriately. But here's my 2 cents:

From the Argand plane perspective, multiplying a complex number by $i$ is equivalent to rotating it about a circle (with radius = modulus of complex number) counterclockwise by 90 degrees. So ask yourself where you end up when you take $i$ and multiply it with $i$ twice.

Comment: Yes.  Many questions and confusions about complex numbers become simple and obvious when thinking about the geometric interpretation.

Answer (score 13):

$\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ is correct in the following sense: In an arbitrary field (here it is the field of complex numbers) the root $\sqrt{a}$ is *an* element in some field extension such that $\sqrt{a}^2=a$. It is not uniquely determined, for if $b$ is a root, then also $-b$ is a root (and these only coincide when $a=0$ or the characteristic is $2$). Now the correct statement is:

- If $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ are roots of $a$ resp. $b$, then $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is a root of $ab$.

If we define $\sqrt{a}$ to be the *set* of all roots of $a$, then $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ even holds verbatim. For example, $\sqrt{-1}=\{\pm i\}$ then, and $\sqrt{(-1) (-1)} = \sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-1}$ holds since both sides equal $\{\pm 1\}$.

If $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$, one usually denotes by $\sqrt{a}$ the unique root of $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^+$, but this definition doesn't work properly for complex numbers or other fields.

Comment: +i for viewing square root as a multivalued function.

Comment: "If we define... holds verbatim": No. In the field $\Bbb F_3$ one has $\{1,2\}=\sqrt 1=\sqrt{2\times 2}\neq \sqrt2\times\sqrt 2=\emptyset\times\emptyset$.

Comment: Thanks. I've corrected the definition of $\sqrt{a}$.

Comment: My only upvote related to this question goes to you for bringing up the special case of characteristic two :-)

Answer (score 8):

When you write $i=\sqrt{-1}$ then this is something that is sometimes useful and sensible, but really has to be done with care. All that really says is that $i^2=-1$, and of course $(-i)^2=-1$ holds as well. So correctly your calculation only yields
$$(i^3)^2=i^2\cdot i^2\cdot i^2=(-1)(-1)(-1)=-1=i^2,$$
which is true.

Answer (score 7):

Multiplying by $i$ in the complex plane amounts to a counterclockwise turn of $90$ degrees. Hence it is geometrically clear that $i^3 = -i$, as the following drawing shows

[image]

Regarding your equations, as remarked already, $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ holds only for positive real $a$ and $b$, so you cannot use it with complex numbers.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt[n]z$ does not return a single value, but *n* complex values. Hence your confusion, since both *i* and $-i$ are among the square roots of $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Simple Answer to this question

as  $i^2=-1$, if you break $i^3$ into  $i^2\cdot i$ then you insert  $-1$ into the place of $i^2$ you will get $(-1)\cdot i =-i$

this is the simple trick behind it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! You can learn how to use MathJaX [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score -2):

Someone posted earlier that it is i x i x i which is -1 x i, ie -i (but the post seems to have been deleted!

But that's all there is to it. It doesn't matter what i represents, the algebra will be consistent. But to prove it, substituting the value of i, ie (√-1), you get

√-1 x √-1 x √-1 
= -1 x √-1
= -(√-1)
= -i

However it may be worth mentioning that i is not a complex number as has been suggested - it is an irrational number. A complex number is of the form (x +iy)

Comment: $i$ is not an irrational number, it's an imaginary number. All real numbers and all imaginary numbers can also be considered complex numbers: they can be written as $x + 0 ⋅ i$ or $0 + y ⋅ i$.

Comment: $i=x+iy$ with $x=0$ and $y=1$.