# Imaginary numbers and exponent arithmetic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

This is a very basic question but it's been driving me crazy for a while...
I know that $i^3 = i^2*i = (-1)i = -i$

But why does the following reasoning give me the wrong answer?
$i^3 = (i^2)^{3/2} = (-1)^{3/2} = (-1)^{1/2} = i$

Thanks

Comment: my guess is because you are using exponent laws meant to give positive answers or that you forget that all numbers have two sqrts and one of them for -1 is -i.

Comment: You expect $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$, but even with real numbers this is not always true.  For example, $$-1=(-1)^{2/2}\color{red}\ne((-1)^2)^{1/2}=1^{1/2}=1$$

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee A number cannot equal multiple things.

Comment: it's not there are two sqrts for all values that's why sqrt unless taken to mean the positive sqrt is not a function. if you believe a negative times a negative is a positive, you have to accept as one of the consequences that -1^2=1^2 for example.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee Of course, but you were suggesting we interpret $1^{1/2}=\pm1$, which would then imply many false things.  You can only choose one value, usually the positive.

Comment: Oh yes, and welcome to math.SE: since you are new, some basic information about writing math may be found [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and  [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). I'd also recommend checking [here](http://goo.gl/PlJyV) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/search)

Comment: Search tip: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers?sort=frequent&pageSize=50

Comment: Very similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/611529/why-is-i3-the-complex-number-i-equal-to-i-instead-of-i