# $1/\sqrt{-a/b} = i \sqrt{b/a}$ or $-i\sqrt{b/a}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

In a book I am reading, I'm following an equation that has the line:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{-\frac{a}{b}}} = \sqrt{\frac{-b}{a}} = i\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$$

but while I was working ahead I did:

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{ -\frac{a}{b}}} = \frac{1}{i \sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}} = -i\sqrt{\frac{b}{a}}$$

Which is correct? Both?

Comment: It's best to avoid the notation $\sqrt{x}$ unless $x$ is a positive real number.

Comment: It helps (in this case, at least) to peruse the `Related` column on the right-hand side, first. This question is essentially the same as $\,i = \sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{-1}}= \dfrac{\sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{-1}}=\dfrac{1}{i}=-i\,$, which in turn is essentially the same as [Simple Complex Number Problem: $1 = -1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3210/simple-complex-number-problem-1-1), which is at the very top of the `Related` list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second one is correct. Implicit in the assumptions in the first is using an identity like

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt x} = \sqrt{\frac 1 x}.$$

Although this is correct for $x \in \mathbb{R}^+$, it does not extend to negative or to complex numbers. There are quite a few false proofs based on the premise that $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt a \cdot \sqrt{b}$ holds unconditionally!