# About Uniform Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin nx}{n}$ on $[0,2\pi]$

Tags: uniform-convergence

> Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\sin nx}{n}$ uniform convergent on $[0,2\pi]$?

I think it is not. However, I could not prove it by Cauchy's criterion.

Comment: No, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28830/does-sum-frac-sinnxn-converge-uniformly-for-all-x-in-0-2-pi) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29186/uniform-convergence-problem?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180624/convergence-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-1n1-sinnxn).

**Hint:** Notice that the series is the Fourier series of the function

$$ -\frac{\pi+x}{2}. $$

Now, use the following result:

**Theorem:** The Fourier series of a $2\pi$-periodic continuous and piecewise smooth function converges uniformly.

Comment: It's the Fourier series of the periodic extension of your function over $[0,2\pi]$. This is not continuous at even integer multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @DavidMitra: We know it is the periodic extension. I just gave him a hint to think and reach a conclusion. Read the [comments](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383129/intervals-where-the-function-is-similar-to-the-fourier-series) under this post.