# How to prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}n=\frac{\pi-1}{2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, exponentiation

One of my classmates challenged me to solve $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}n=\;?$

With a simple c program I found that $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{1048576}\frac{\sin n}n\approx1.070796$.
Later I found $\displaystyle1.070796\approx\frac{\pi-1}{2}$.
My classmate told me I guessed right, but he ask me to prove it, and he gave me a hint that $\displaystyle e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$, though I can't see the relationship between the question and the hint.

So how to prove $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin n}n=\frac{\pi-1}{2}$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proving that the sequence $F\_{n}(x)=\sum\limits\_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$ is boundedly convergent on $\mathbb{R}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is)

Comment: @Norbert While the accepted answer to that question answers this one, aren't they different questions? This one asks what the series converges to. All that that one asks is for a proof of convergnece.

Comment: @Norbert The answer in your link confuses me. And what about my friend's hint that $\displaystyle e^{i\theta} = \cos\theta + i \sin\theta$?

Comment: I wish my friends challenged me like that :(

Comment: @johnchen902, if "your friend" *really* hinted you that $\,e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\;$ and you did not know that before hand, it may be this exercise is not suited to your mathematics level.

Comment: @DonAntonio I know that *beforehand*. My friend is just giving me a clue to solve.

Comment: Check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399238/about-uniform-convergence-of-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nxn-on-0-2-pi).

Comment: What a crazy identity. Sin(n) will go all over the range of sine because sine is an ergodic function over the integers. Yet it sums to such a nice closed form.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Make use of the following fact: For $\vert z \vert \leq 1$ and $z \neq 1$, we have
$$\log(1-z) = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^k}k$$
Take $z=e^i$ and look at the imaginary part.

We hence have
$$\log(1-e^i) = - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{ik}}k \implies \text{Imag}(\log(1-e^i)) = \text{Imag}\left(- \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{ik}}k \right)$$
which gives us
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(k)}k = - \text{Imag}(\log(1-e^i))$$
$$\log(1-e^i) = \log \left(2\sin^2(1/2) - 2i \sin(1/2) \cos(1/2)\right) = \log(2\sin(1/2)e^{-i \pi/2}e^{i/2})$$
Hence,
$$\text{Imag}(\log(1-e^i)) = \dfrac{1-\pi}2$$ which gives us
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{\sin(k)}k = \dfrac{\pi-1}2$$

Comment: That, my friend, is an epic observation. :-)

Comment: But my question is how we get that.  Working it out is no simple task.  (I mean the logarithm and all that, as it doesn't simplify nicely)

Comment: What is $\text{Imag}$? My first thought, it stood for *imagine*?

Comment: @user477343 I think it stands for "imaginary part."

Comment: @Y.Forman thanks for telling me :)