# How to prove $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}n=\frac{\pi-1}2$ using only real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, alternative-proof, pi

I noticed that a lot of the time, people ask whether the following sum converges:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}n$$

Though I've never stopped to ask what it equaled.  According to this [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/402633/how-to-prove-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sin-nn-frac-pi-12), the sum is given as

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}n=\frac{\pi-1}2$$

The solution involves realizing $\sin(n)=\Im e^{in}$ and the Taylor expansion for the natural logarithm.

While thats great and all, how can I prove this using only real numbers?

Comment: Find the (real) Fourier series of the function $x \mapsto \frac{\pi- x}{2}$ on $[0,2\pi]$.

Comment: @DanielFischer If you could do that that'd be great

Comment: How about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/proving-that-the-sequence-f-nx-sum-limits-k-1n-frac-sinkxk-is)?

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh, thanks for the nice find.

Comment: I thought Fourier transformation involve Complex numbers.

Comment: @Nick, have you seen [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26848)?

Comment: @J.M.isnotamathematician Fair enough.  Still, an extremely minor edit on a question that is nearly a year old.  But, if you insist on making the change, I won't re-revert.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested in comments, lets use fourier series. =). From [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/374244/169193) we have the fourier series of $x$, valid in the range $[-\pi, \pi]$:
$$
x = -2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n}\sin(nx)
$$

If we insert: $x=\pi-1$, it will elliminate the $(-1)^n$ from the formula. 
$$
\sin(nx) = 
\sin(n\pi - n) = 
\sin(n\pi)\cos(n)-\cos(n\pi)\sin(n) = 
-(-1)^n\sin(n)
$$

Then:
$$
\pi-1 = 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\sin(n) \quad\implies\quad
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n)}{n} = \frac{\pi-1}{2}
$$