# Evaluate $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n)}{n}$$

converges to a specific value. Convergence tests of any kind are available in a quick search, but I'm struggling to find the proof that this sequence converges to $(\pi - 1)/2$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/402636/132192), complex logarithms are used.

I do not have any knowledge about series and sequences, just a real analysis / real functions background.

Is it possible to make the same proof, using only real functions? If yes, where can I find this proof?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3361589/proof-that-sum-limits-n-1-infty-1n1-sinn-overn-1-over2

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2031572/how-to-prove-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac-sinnn-frac-pi-12-using-only.

Comment: $f(x)=\text{sinc}(x)$ is an even entire function of order $1$. By the Euler-Maclaurin summation formula it follows that $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\text{sinc}(n)=-\frac{1}{2}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\text{sinc}(x)\,dx=\frac{\pi-1}{2},$$ since the odd derivatives at the origin all equal zero.