Is $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}$ uniformly convergent in $(0,2\pi)$?
I'm pretty sure this series is divergent because $|\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}| \leq \frac{1}{k}$, which is a divergent harmonic series. I'm not sure on how to formally prove this, i thought about using the Cauchy criterion for uniform convergence, but i didn't get anywhere. Series are a new topic for me, any help?

How are you 'pretty sure'? Your 'argument' $|\frac{\sin{kx}}{k}| \leq \frac1k$ indicates nothing.

Note that $\frac1{k^2} < \frac1k$ but this doesn't imply $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1{k^2}$ diverges.

Try using summation by parts.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/399238 Btw, before asking about uniform convergence, you should tell us what you know about pointwise convergence.

Hint.  Graph a partial sum and the limit.  Ask yourself whether they are uniformly close to each other.


I tried graphing the partial sum and iI got a similar graph, however I still don't understand how do i formally prove the divergence. If the series were convergent and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}$ were convergent i would use the Weierstrass criterion to prove the convergence of the original series.

In Fourier series, the presence of a discontinuity induces the so-called "Gibbs phenomenon" ("overshoot") preventing uniform convergence.

The picture shows that, near the endpoints, the two graphs are far,far apart (approximately $\pi/2$ and $0$).  If we show that is true for every partial sum, then we know that convergence it not uniform.

@GEEdgar This is precisely the Gibbs phenomenon

I think, in this case, the OP can answer his question without knowing the Gibbs phenomenon.  But of course the OP may want to look it up for future reference.
