# Convergence of serie

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{k\sin(2kx)}{4k^2-1}$ converge? I tried to use the tests, but I couldn't get anything. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Which tests have you tried?

Comment: What do we know  about $x$ ?

Comment: root and reason test. I couldn't find a function to try the comparison test.

Comment: @kmitov nothing.. $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: After the usual fiddling, this will reduce to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28830/does-sum-frac-sinnxn-converge-uniformly-for-all-x-in-0-2-pi) question.

Comment: I would suggest that you look at [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Answer (score 1):

It converges, by Dirichlet's test, since:

- the sequence $\left(\frac k{4k^2-1}\right)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is monotonic and converges to $0$;
- the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sin(2kx)$ has bounded partial sums.