# Euler's Identity

Tags: solution-verification

Can anyone explain  where did I actually commit a mistake?
In the end I got the result that e^(2\pi )=1 (which is clearly not true)
 [image: I showed this to my teacher but he refused to tell me where I was wrong.]

Comment: $a^{b}$ is not uniquely defined number for $a,b \in \mathbb C$ and your manipulations are invalid. Until you are familiar with Complex Analysis you should use $a^{b}$ only for $a>0$.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The trick comes when you take the non-integer power of a negative number or a complex number with a non-zero imaginary part as Kavi mentioned. [A contradiction involving exponents](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/a-contradiction-involving-exponents)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following paradox:
$$(1) ^{0.5}=(-1\times -1) ^{0.5}=(-1) ^{0.5}\times (-1) ^{0.5}=i\times i=-1$$. 
(Since $x^y$ is not well defined for $x, y\in\mathbb{C}$