# Why is this wrong (complex numbers and proving 1=-1)?

Tags: complex-numbers, fake-proofs

$$(e^{2πi})^{1/2}=1^{1/2}$$$$(e^{πi})=1$$ $$-1=1$$ I think it is due to not taking the principle value but please can someone explain why this is wrong in detial, thanks.

Comment: Since this appears in your question, what is your definition of $x^{1/2}$ when $x$ is not a nonnegative real number?

Comment: Note that "proof" is a *thing*: a noun. "Prove" is the corresponding verb: We aim to *prove* that X holds by writing a *proof* that X holds.

Comment: sorry i am dyslexic and hence why there is often a lot of grammar + spelling mistakes in my questions!

Comment: possible duplicate of [$-1$ is not $ 1$, so where is the mistake?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/1-is-not-1-so-where-is-the-mistake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used two different branches of the function $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Note that even in exponential form $(e^{x})^\frac{1}{2}$ has two different branches: $e^{\frac{x}{2}}$ and $e^{\frac{x}{2}+\frac{2 \pi i}{2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

You basically claimed

$$ \sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{(1)^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad -1 = 1 $$

but the square root is not a map, i.e. $\sqrt{a}$ can have multiple solutions. In particular, it is not the inverse of $x^2$.