# Confused with imaginary numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

In 9th grade I had an argument with my teacher that

${i}^{3}=i$

where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

But my teacher insisted (as is the accepted case) that:

${i}^{3}=-i$

**My Solution:**

${i}^3=(\sqrt{-1})^3$

${i}^3=\sqrt{(-1)^3}$

${i}^3=\sqrt{-1\times-1\times-1}$

${i}^3=\sqrt{-1}$

${i}^3=i$

**Generally accepted solution:**

${i}^3=(\sqrt{-1})^3$

${i}^3=\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-1}$

${i}^3=-\sqrt{-1}$

${i}^3=-i$

What is so wrong with my approach? Is it not logical?

I am using the positive square root. There seems to be something about the order in which the power should be raised? There must be a logical reason, and I need help understanding it.

Comment: You might want to look at this: [Simple complex Number Problem: 1=-1.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12)

Comment: As Avid's comment suggests, the issue is that you can't go from line 1 to 2.

Comment: Of course $-1=1$ because $-1 = \sqrt{-1}^2 = \sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{1} = 1$. Thus $-\mathrm i = -1\mathrm i = 1\mathrm i = \mathrm i$. :-)

Comment: About "I am using the positive square root": No, the notion of "positive" is not defined for complex numbers.

Comment: The problem is that there are _two_ square roots of $-1$, and $i$ is just one of those. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 13):

In a nutshell the square root function is not single valued.  So you cannot always say $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\cdot \sqrt b$.  Otherwise you could also prove $1=-1$ as follows: $1=\sqrt1=\sqrt{-1\cdot-1}=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=(\sqrt{-1})^2=-1$.

Answer (score 12):

The error is in saying $i=\sqrt{-1}$. The correct statement is $i^2=-1$ and we're only allowed to use this property.

Thus
$$
i^3=i^2\cdot i=(-1)\cdot i=-i
$$

*Never* substitute $\sqrt{-1}$ for $i$: it just leads to errors, because the standard identity $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{ab}$ just holds for *real* and *non negative* numbers.

Comment: I really like this answer +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better proof than the given "generally accepted proof":

$i^3 = i^2 \cdot i = -1 \cdot i = -i$

Answer (score 2):

I think it is always healthier to avoid square roots. If we had equality $i^3=i$, then
$$
-1=i\times i=i\times i^3=i^2\times i^2=(-1)(-1)=1. 
$$
Or, you could simply check: $i^3=i^2\times i=(-1)i=-i$.

Comment: +1 Very true. I always introduce the imaginary unit as $i^2=-1$ and thus always avoid the square root!

Answer (score 1):

The number $\sqrt{-1}$ is a two valued function with values $\{i,-i\}$ and hence the statement
$$
\sqrt{-1}=i
$$
is not true.

If you define the square function on the principal branch, then you can write $\sqrt{-1}=i$ but you can't pass the power into the square.

Comment: The idea to define $\sqrt{-1}=i$ is already an issue to begin with. See egreg's answer.