# Paradox - minus one equals one using square roots

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic, roots, fake-proofs

I was looking on Howard Eves's book "An Introduction to the History of Mathematics" and I stumbled upon a demonstration on how $-1 = 1$. The demonstration follows:

$$ \sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{-1} $$

$$ \sqrt{-1\over1} = \sqrt{1\over-1}$$

$$ {\sqrt{-1}\over\sqrt{1}} = {\sqrt{1}\over\sqrt{-1}}$$

$$ \sqrt{-1}\cdot\sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{1}\cdot\sqrt{1} $$

Thus:

$$  -1 = 1  $$

My question is simple: how can it be? Where is the error? Is that a paradox?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12 already addresses this question.

Comment: roots don't obey quite the laws you think they do (ie for real roots) when they have complex numbers under them...

Answer (score 1):

The "rule" you use from line 2 to 3 doesn't hold for negative numbers. I.e.
$$
i=\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{\frac1{-1}}\neq\frac1{\sqrt{-1}}=-i
$$

Answer (score 0):

```
a / i != a * i
```

in the step 3 to 4.