# Integrating $z^i$ over the unit circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, branch-cuts

Why is there a difference between integrating it over a unit circle parametrized over $t \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ and $t \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}\right]$?

Comment: Is the second interval perhaps meant to be $[\pi/2,3\pi/2]$?

Comment: It would perhaps help if you wrote the integral out in full

Comment: In agreement with @AlexanderMcFarlane, I say that your question can not be answered till you show us the parametrization you used. It seems to me that if you are integrating a continuous function, the value of your function will be different at the two endpoints.

Comment: @Scounged: yes! It should be, I copied and pasted out of laziness and forgot to remove the minus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference comes from $e^{i\theta}$ giving different signs of $\pm i$ for the different angles.

The first approach I would always take on these problems is by looking for branch cuts in the complex logarithm by doing the sneaky move of replacing as,

$$
z^i = 
e^{i\ln{z}} 
=
e^{i\ln{re^{i\theta}}}
$$
But $r=1$ on the unit circle,

$$
e^{i\ln{e^{i\theta}}}
$$

Now at this point I'll link to an [explanation on branch cuts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1602274/272850) (by someone related to me!) with relevance to the complex phase $e^{i\phi}$, which should give you an awareness of some of the concepts as you have a complex phase with a phase angle of $\phi=\ln{e^{i\theta}}$

Also note that $\ln(\pm i)=\pm \frac{i\pi}{2}$

As it turned out your phase wasn't actually even complex as all the values you provide give a nice $\phi = \ln{(\pm i)}$ so you will obtain something like $e^{\mp \pi /2}$ where the difference is due to my opening assertion

Comment: Isn't $z^i = \exp(i \log z)$, not $i \exp(\log z)$?

Comment: Yes I'm just editing now I'm typing it on my iPhone though so inserted the $i$ one character early!