# $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}=x$; Is the condition true always, sometimes, or never?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}=x$$

This equation was provided to me, and I had to find out if this condition was sometimes, always, or never true.

At first my initial thought was that the condition will **ALWAYS** be true, since $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}$ evaluates to $\sqrt[4]{x^4}$, which evaluates to $x$. Since $x=x$, the condition is always true.

However, as I was about to put Always as my solution, I realized that **SOMETIMES** might be the correct answer. My process was that $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}$ can be restated as $(-x)^{4^{\frac{1}{4}}}$, and after multiplying the exponents, this is simply $(-x)^1$ or $-x$.

$-x=x$ is only true for the value $x=0$, so I put **SOMETIMES** as my solution.

Is sometimes, or always the solution to this question?

**If you find the solution to this, remember, you are answering this important question:**

In which order do you simplify the expression, do you carry out the exponent to the base first, or do you simplify exponents first?

Comment: Is your equality true if $x=-124$?

Comment: "My process was that $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}$ can be restated as $(-x)^{4^{\frac{1}{4}}}$":  Think about $|-1| = \sqrt{(-1)^2}$ restated as $(-1)^{2^{\frac12}} = -1$.

Comment: You seem to believe that according to your work $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}=x$ is only true when $x=0$.  It is in fact true for all non-negative (*real*) values of $x$.  Notice for example when $x=1$ we have $\sqrt[4]{(-1)^4}=\sqrt[4]{1}=1$.  Remember to evaluate parenthetical phrases first.

Comment: This is what I initially thought, but why can't you simplify the exponents first?

Comment: Because the exponent $4$ is underneath of the radical.  $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}$ is different than $\sqrt[4]{(-x)}^4$.  Think of it as $\sqrt[4]{((-x)^4)}$ if you like.  As for "*why can't we change the order?*" or "*why are these actually different?*" consider reading this question: [Why $\sqrt{-1\times -1}\neq \sqrt{-1}^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12).

Comment: Thank you! This means my book is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is **always true that** $$\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}=|x|$$

Indeed  **by definition** the square root of $a\geq0$ $$\sqrt[4] a$$ is the **non negative** value $b$ such that $$b^4=a$$

Comment: Why is the absolute value of one side being taken?

Comment: @YashJain This is the definition of the principle square root.

Comment: However, our math textbook says that this is sometimes true. Should we assume that the book is wrong then?

Comment: @YashJain it is *sometimes* true that $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}=x$.  It is *always* true that $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}=|x|$.  These are different statements and both of them are correct.

Comment: because by definition of square root, the square root of $a\geq0$ $\sqrt[4] a$ is the non negative value $b$ such that $b^4=a$

Answer (score 2):

It should be sometimes since there are two cases to consider:

**CASE 1 ($x \ge 0$):** In this case, we have $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4}=\sqrt[4]{x^4} = x$

**CASE 2 ($x < 0$):** In this case, we have $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^4} = \sqrt[4]{x^4} = -x$ because $x$ is already a negative number and the result should be positive.

Here, notice that we always do the operation $(-x)^4 = x^4$ first, then the $\sqrt[4]{x^4} = x$ or $-x$ according to the value of $x$.

And we can combine these results as $\sqrt[4]{(-x)^{4}} = |x|$ as you can see from the above cases.

Comment: Is there any information online which tells me we apply the exponent to the base first?

Comment: I don't know any online source but I can give you an example where your approach is valid. If you have an expression such as $(\sqrt[4]{-1})^4$ then you can write it as $((-1)^{\frac{1}{4}})^4 = (-1)^1 = -1$.