# Simplify the cube root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How would one simplify the cube root of $x^{64}$? Please show the solution step by step if possible. Been a while since I took math so please forgive the simplicity of this question... Thank you in advance.

Comment: One reason for this question would be to emphasise that the answer is not $x^4$ (which some might be trapped into thinking by $4^3=64$)

Answer (score 3):

$\sqrt[3]{x^{64}}=\sqrt[3]{x^{21\cdot 3+1}}=x^{21}\sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: You have not taken into account what happens when $x$ is negative.

Comment: Is that a valid reason for a downvote?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Yes, it absolutely is.  $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ but logic like this and above would have you believe that $\sqrt{x^2}=x^{\frac{2}{2}}=x$

Comment: Shouldn't a $\pm$ or a 'for $x \ge 0$' solve it?

Comment: @JMoravitz The question is about  a cubic root, not a square root, and $\sqrt[3]{x^3}=x$ independently on the sign of $x$.

Comment: What is the result of the left-hand-side of your answer when $x=-1$ then?  What is the result of the right-hand side when $x=-1$?  What is the *principal* cubic root of $-1$?  Is it real?  Is the notation $\sqrt[3]{x}$ used for the *realvalued* root or the *principal* root?

Comment: @JMoravitz This is marked precalculus. Clearly we are not working with complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain how you got that answer? How does the 21 come out. Thanks

Comment: @user522534 The answer follows from the general rules to deal with the powers. $21$ is the integer part of $64/3$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky You should really elaborate some more on why $\sqrt[3]{x^{64}}=\sqrt[3]{x^{21\cdot 3+1}}=x^{21}\sqrt[3]{x}$ may be valid here, while the very similarly looking $\sqrt[6]{x^{68}}=\sqrt[6]{x^{11\cdot 6+2}} \ne x^{11}\sqrt[6]{x^2}$ is clearly not.

Comment: So essentially we have cube root of x^7 * x^7 * x^7 * x^3 * x? Then we take out the 3 “x^7” ‘s adding up to 21 (since multiplying exponents is really adding them) and left with an “x” inside the cube root? Only thing I dont get is dont we have an x^3 left as well and do we take this out? Sorry, I know I am dumbing it down...

Comment: @JMoravitz Even if we allow with complex roots, the value of the left hand side is the same as the value of the right hand side.

Comment: What is $(-1)^{64}$?  It is $1$.  What is the principal cube root of $1$?  It is again $1$.  Meanwhile, what is $(-1)^{21}$?  It is $(-1)$.  What is the principal cube root of $(-1)$?  It is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.  What is their product?  $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.  Is $1$ equal to $-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$?  No.  Is your left hand expression equal to the right when $x=-1$?  No.

Comment: @user522534 No, we have a cube root of $x^{21}\cdot x^{21}\cdot x^{21}\cdot x$. We know, that $\sqrt[3]{y^3}=y$ and $\sqrt[3]{z\cdot t}=\sqrt[3]{z} \cdot \sqrt[3]{t}$ for any real $y,z,t$. So $\sqrt[3]{x^{21}\cdot x^{21}\cdot x^{21}\cdot x}=
\sqrt[3]{x^{21}\cdot x^{21}\cdot x^{21}}\cdot \sqrt[3]{x}= x^{21}\cdot \sqrt[3]{x}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz What do you mean by the principal cube root? And why  the principal cube root of $1$ is $1$, whereas the principal cube root of $(-1)$ is $\frac 12+\frac{\sqrt 3}2i$?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH. My brain just connected the dots. Total brain malfunction... Obviously math is not my forte! Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @JMoravitz I have to go to my university, so answering your possible future question I tell that for real $x$ and complex roots at both sides we have sets  $\{1,\varepsilon,\varepsilon^2\}|x|^{64/3}$, where $\varepsilon\ne 1$ is the complex cubic root of $1$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky the principal $n$'th root of a number is the $n$'th root whose argument is closest to zero.  Writing a number in polar form $re^{i\theta}$ where $r$ is non-negative real and $0\leq\theta<2\pi$, one has $\sqrt[n]{re^{i\theta}}=\sqrt[n]{r}\cdot e^{i\theta/n}$ where $\sqrt[n]{r}$ is defined as usual for non-negative real numbers.  [See $n$'th root on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root) and [$n$'th complex roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root#nth_roots)

Comment: OK, I should go now, so I look at your links later. Since I work rather in algebra than in complex analysis, for me complex roots constitute a set and I don’t demand that the expression $\sqrt[3]{x}$ is reserved to represent some specific element of this set.  Thank you for you attentivity, I didn’t consider so deep issues when I wrote my answer.

Answer (score 3):

$x^{64}=x^{\frac{64}{3}\times3}$.

Hence, $^3\sqrt{x^{64}}=x^{\frac{64}{3}}$.

Even when $x$ is negative, it yields the same results at there is an even power of $64$ which cancels out the negative.

On the other hand, the similar looking $x^\frac{5}{3}$ does not hold for negative values as $5$ is a odd power, and hence the negative sign is not cancelled.

Hence, we can form a generalisation for all negative $x$: for $x^\frac{a}{3}$, if $a$ is even, the result is positive.  If $a$ is odd, the result is negative.

Comment: You have not taken into account what happens when $x$ is negative.

Comment: it is the same... the power 64 cancels the negative

Comment: mmm... no.  If you want to be pedantic, when you use [non-integer rational exponents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Rational_exponents) you actually get a multivalued expression, or if you want to make it single-valued you use the denominator of the rational number first rather than the numerator, specifically using the principal root.  Your expression $x^{\frac{64}{3}}$ under such a convention yields a nonreal complex number for $x=-1$

Comment: i tried $x=-1$ and got 1.

Comment: @XcoderX You should really elaborate some more on why $^3\sqrt{x^{64}}=x^{\frac{64}{3}}$ may be valid here, while the very similarly looking $\sqrt[6]{x^{10}}=x^{\frac{5}{3}}$ is clearly not.

Comment: Okay.  I will do that

Comment: @XcoderX "I tried $x=-1$ and got $1$."  [Wolfram-alpha disagrees](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(-1)%5E(64%2F3)) as do I and pen-and-paper calculations should verify.  Notice below the entry box a phrase "Assuming the principal root | Use the real-valued root instead" or the opposite "Assuming the real-valued root | Use the principal root instead."  Remembering that the convention is and should be to use the principal root for this notation, one shouldn't get a real valued answer to $(-1)^{\frac{64}{3}}$.

Comment: As per your edit in regards to the $\sqrt[6]{x^{10}}$ vs $x^{\frac{5}{3}}$ side question that dxiv tried to pose to get you to think about the underlying issues at work here, you seemed to miss the point.  Even if you were to use the real-valued root instead of the principal root, according to your logic you might say $\sqrt[6]{x^{10}}=x^{\frac{10}{6}}=x^{\frac{5}{3}}$, but by plugging in $-1$ you have a positive number on the far left but a negative number on the far right, or $\sqrt{x^2}=x^{\frac{2}{2}}=x$, again with $x=-1$ gives a positive number on the left but a negative number on right.

Comment: The question to think about here is: Is $\sqrt[b]{x^a}=x^{\frac{a}{b}}$ actually a valid simplification *for all $x$* including negative values, and given $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{c}{d}$, is $x^{\frac{a}{b}}=x^{\frac{c}{d}}$ actually a valid simplification *for all $x$* including negative values?  The above examples should tell you that at least one of these two simplifications is incorrect.  Which, and why?

Answer (score -1):

You need to be careful.  Assuming that $x$ is real, one has $x^{64}$ is always a non-negative real number, and the cube root of a non-negative real number will again be a non-negative real.

$\sqrt[3]{x^{64}}=|x|^{\frac{64}{3}}=|x^{21}\cdot \sqrt[3]{x}|$

Without such care, one can arrive at incorrect results such as $\sqrt{x^2}=x$, which would imply things such as $1=-1$ (*by plugging in $-1$ in for $x$*)

Comment: As Alex Ravsky has pointed out, for odd powers this is unnecessary. The equation $\sqrt[3]{a^3} = a$ holds for all real $a$.

Comment: I am not taking issue with $\sqrt[3]{a^3}=a$.  I am taking issue with all of the other erroneous simplifications being made @YakovShklarov.

Comment: @E.H.E. $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ and not $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ is a classic example of why care needs to be taken in such things which one can see in problems such as [Why $\sqrt{-1\times -1}\neq \sqrt{-1}^2?$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12). And I take back what I said earlier. I *do* take issue with saying $\sqrt[3]{a^3}=a$. That would be true if we were using the *realvalued* cube root rather than the more standard convention of using the *principal* cube root where such a simplification is false. $\sqrt[3]{(-1)^3}=\sqrt[3]{-1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$

Comment: @E.H.E Both other answers handwave that $\,(x^a)^b=x^{a \cdot b}\,$, which is not true in general. Even if that works in this case, any answer that doesn't emphasize *why* it happens to work here, and where else it does *not* work, is a dangerously incomplete answer. Whoever downvoted *this* answer did not understand that point, and is at risk of falling for any one of those $\,-1=(-1)^{2/2}=\sqrt{(-1)^2}=1\,$ perennial questions that get posted on MSE every other week.