# ¿Where does equality fail?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fake-proofs

I know this: $\sqrt{x}^2 = |x|$, but

$\sqrt{(-1)^2} = \sqrt{(-1)^2}$

$(-1)^\frac{2}{2} = \sqrt{-1 * -1}$

$(-1)^1 = \sqrt{1}$

$-1 = 1^2$, then

$-1 = 1$

What step is wrong?

Comment: $\sqrt x \neq |x|$, do you mean $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$?

Comment: Yes sorry, edited

Comment: At the very first step. Consider amending to $(\sqrt{|x|})^2 = |x|$.

Comment: You have misunderstood the actual identity $\sqrt {x^2}=\sqrt{(x^2)}=\lvert x\rvert$ (notice where the overline stops), which holds for all $x\in\Bbb R$, for the made-up thing $(\sqrt x)^2=\lvert x\rvert$, which does not hold because $\sqrt x$, whenever it is defined, is made so that it satisfies $(\sqrt x)^2=x$.

Answer (score -1):

The square root function has a branch cut discontinuity on the negative real axis. That means you can't do this: $\sqrt{(-1)(-1)}=\sqrt{-1}\,\sqrt{-1}$, because you'd be approaching that discontinuity from two different directions, and expecting them to be equal. For your derivation, $((-1)^2)^{1/2}\not=((-1)^{1/2})^2$, a step implicit in your derivation.

Comment: This doesn't really have to do with the branch cut. After all, you can choose the branch cut to lie on a different axis. The key issue is that the property $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ doesn't hold anymore.

Comment: @user296602: And the reason you can't do that if both $a$ and $b$ are negative is because you're crossing the default branch cut. If someone were to specify a different branch cut, that'd be fine, but the algebra above would have to look different.

Comment: See @Alexander McFarlane's answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1602274 for a more detailed explanation.