# Can $\sqrt{35}$ be written as $\sqrt{-1}\times\sqrt{-35}$? Why/Why not?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

If

1) $\sqrt{-a} = \sqrt{a} \times \sqrt{-1}$

2) $\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{a}\times \sqrt{1}$

Then, according to me $\sqrt{a}$ could also be written as $\sqrt{-a}\times\sqrt{-1}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: This is in spirit a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12.

Comment: you cannot because the operation $\sqrt{a\cdot b} = \sqrt a +\sqrt b$ is defined only for $a,b\gt 0$. If not youll open up the gate to a lot of messy things .

Comment: If you multiply a square root of $a$ by a square root of $b$, you get a square root of $ab$, but not necessarily the one you first thought of.

Comment: Be careful of your definitions. The usual use of the √ function takes a positive real number to a positive real number. You can extend this to work in the complex plane, but which of the two square roots are you going to use? If you are going to use both, then you can write that, but note you aren't working with functions at that point.

Comment: If you admit this, you have $-1=\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{-1}=\sqrt{1}=1$, not really good for doing maths.

Comment: Okay I understand now that the square root function is only defined for all positive real numbers but I saw something like this in my textbook: √-2 = √2 x √-1 = √2 x i. If the function isn't defined for negative real number then why can we consider 'iota' or √-1.

Comment: Maybe you should add to your question a quoted paragraph or two from your textbook so we can see _exactly_ what it said, not just “something like this.” Also let us know the author’s name and the title and edition of the book (in case someone has access to a copy).

Answer (score 3):

You must define what you mean by the square root.

It is usually understood to mean a function $\sqrt{\cdot}\,:[0,+\infty)\longrightarrow[0,+\infty)$, meaning it's only defined on nonnegative real numbers, and its result is always a nonnegative real number. In other words, we always take the positive square root: $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$ $($which is not necessarily $a)$.
This function is multiplicative: $\sqrt{a\cdot b} = \sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b}$.
However, the domain of the function *must* be respected, and trying to apply this relation to numbers outside the domain does not make sense (because the function isn't even defined at those points!).

In other contexts (for instance, complex analysis), one generally understands that square roots (and other $n$-th roots) are multivalued functions: any nonzero complex number has $n$ distinct $n$-th roots. In this context, we don't say that '$2$ is **the** square root of $4$', but rather that '$2$ is **a** square root of $4$', the other being $-2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\pm i$ are square roots of $-1,$ and $\pm i\sqrt 35$ are square roots of $-35.$
\begin{align}
(i) \times (i\sqrt{35}) & = -\sqrt{35} \\
(-i) \times (i\sqrt{35}) & = +\sqrt{35} \\
(i) \times (-i\sqrt{35}) & = +\sqrt{35} \\
(-i) \times (-i\sqrt{35}) & = -\sqrt{35}
\end{align}
So some care about what is meant by $\text{“ }\sqrt{-35\,} \text{ ''}$ is in order.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{-a}\times\sqrt{-1}$$ is not well-defined, because there are more than one possible answers to that.

As you know a complex number has two square roots, and that is the problem with expressions such as $\sqrt {-5} \sqrt {-1} = \sqrt 5$ because it could as well be  $- \sqrt 5$

Answer (score 0):

By allowing negative and positive values to be solutions to $\sqrt{x}$, we have

\begin{align}
\sqrt{36} & = \pm 6 \\
-6 & = -1 \cdot 6 \\
& = (\sqrt{-1})^2 \cdot (\sqrt{6})^2 \\
& = \sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{6}\cdot \sqrt{6} \\
& = \sqrt{-1} \cdot \sqrt{6} \cdot \sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{6} \\
& = \sqrt{-6} \cdot \sqrt{-6} \\
& = \sqrt{-6\cdot-6} \\
& = \sqrt{36}
\end{align}

**However**, the square function $f(x) = x^2$ is not one to one, and thus does not have a well-defined inverse. Which is essentially how we can "prove" that $x \not= \sqrt{x^2}$. By presuming unique factorization in a field $(\mathbb{C})$ that is not a unique factorization domain, we get a result of limited utility.

Comment: You can write $3\times 5$ or $3\cdot5;$ there's no need to use an asterisk for that. Using an asterisk for ordinary multiplication is a workaround for situations in which one is limited to the characters on the keyboard.