# Negative square roots of Reals in inequalities

Tags: inequality, roots, real-numbers

Where r $ \epsilon \Bbb { R,}$
determine the range of r.

$$\left\lvert 1-2 \sqrt{-r}\right\rvert < 1$$

$$-1< (1-2 \sqrt{-r}) < 1$$

$$-2< (-2\sqrt -r) < 0 $$

$$1>(\sqrt -r) > 0$$

The answer is: $-1<r<0$

So why do I not believe it was found using the following?

continuing from above at $\quad1>(\sqrt -r)> 0 $
$$(1)^2>(\sqrt -r)^2>(0)^2 $$
$$1> -r > 0$$
$$-1<r<0$$

This is where I began to wonder about $\;(\sqrt -r)^2$
and why not...$\;(-{\sqrt -r})^2$ too?

Because $\quad(-{\sqrt -r})*(-{\sqrt -r})\neq \sqrt -r$ or does it? I must keep firm that r is not complex, r is in the reals.
I know I am missing something but am not sure what that is. Can anyone please tell me what I am not understanding about these statements?

Thanks.

Comment: Let $r'=-r$ and do the computation with $r'$ instead. It may be way less confusing this way.

Comment: "*Because $(-\sqrt{-r})*(-\sqrt{-r})\neq \sqrt{-r}$ or does it?*"  You surely have a typo there somewhere, the expression on the left is of cardinality $|r|$ while the expression on the right is only of cardinality $|\sqrt{r}|$.  Either way, you seem to be reaching for something along the lines of how [$\sqrt{(-1)\times(-1)}\neq (\sqrt{-1})^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438/why-sqrt-1-times-1-neq-sqrt-12).

Comment: "I began to wonder about $(\sqrt{-r})^2$ and why not ... $(-\sqrt{-r})^2$ too".  $(\sqrt{-r})^2= (-\sqrt{-r})^2$.  "Because $(-\sqrt{-r})*(-\sqrt{-r})\neq \sqrt{-r}$ or does it".  Well, no, but $(-\sqrt{-r})*(-\sqrt{-r})=(\sqrt{-r})*(\sqrt{-r})=-r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left\lvert 1-2 \sqrt{-r}\right\rvert < 1$$

Let r=-x, then we have  $$\left\lvert 1-2 \sqrt{x}\right\rvert < 1$$

$$-1<1-2 \sqrt{x}<1$$

$$-2<-2 \sqrt{x}<0$$

$$0<2 \sqrt{x}<2$$
$$0<\sqrt{x}<1$$
$$0<x<1$$
$$0<-r<1$$
$$-1<r<0$$